# Is a function that has maximum points a polynomial function?

Tags: polynomials

Just like the title says.

Is a function that has maximum/minimum points guaranteed to be a polynomial function?
Is there any occasion that it cannot be expressed as a polynomial function?

Comment: Obviously not! Look e.g. at $\sin, \cos$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

f(x)=$\frac{1}{x}$ on [1,2] has maximum at x=1, but f(x) isn't a polynomial function.